# Como adicionar a uma propriedade de um objeto usando drop-down list no ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando adicionar um valor a propriedade `Quantidade` do objeto `Moeda`, selecionando dentro de uma lista de objetos atraves de uma drop down list.

Essa é minha model class:

```
public class Moeda
{
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tipo de Moeda")]
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "R$ {0:0.00}")]
        public float Valor { get; set; }
}
```

E estes são meus controllers methods:

```
public IActionResult Add()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(String tipo, int quantidade)
{
    var moeda = await _context.Moeda
                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Tipo == tipo);

    moeda.Quantidade += quantidade;

    _context.Update(moeda);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

E essa a View:

```
@model MaquinaDeTrocoMVC.Models.Moeda
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>The select element</h1>

    <form action="/moedas/add">
        <label for="tipo">Escolha uma moeda</label>
        <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
            <option value="1 Centavo">1 Centavo</option>
            <option value="5 Centavos">5 Centavos</option>
            <option value="10 Centavos">10 Centavos</option>
            <option value="25 Centavos">25 Centavos</option>
            <option value="50 Centavos">50 Centavos</option>
            <option value="1 Real">1 Real</option>
        </select>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Quantidade" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Quantidade" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Quantidade" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>    

</body>
</html>
```

Quando clico no botão submit, ele altera a url para conter o Tipo e a Quantidade vinda da View, porem não executa o Post (Não volta para o Index nem atualiza o banco).
O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você define na sua `Action` um atributo do tipo `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` torna obrigatório que seja passado no seu Form um valor para ele.

Acrescente o código `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` logo após definir o seu `Form`

```
<form action="/moedas/add">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
```

Esse código irá gerar um `input` do tipo `Hidden`, contendo um Token que sua aplicação gerou para essa requisição. Assim evitando que o envio de dados para o servidor seja falsificado.

Exemplo de Input gerado.

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"
value="valor do token gerado pela aplicação" />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, não tinha me atentado a isso, funcionou!